# Separate Kafka listener for each topic using annotations in spring kafka

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

My application is listening to multiple kafka topics. Right now, my listener looks like below, and `my.topics` in property file contains the list of comma separated kafka topics

```
@KafkaListener(topics = ["#{'\${my.topics}'.split(',')}"], groupId = "my.group", containerFactory = "myKafkaFactory")
fun genericMessageListener(myRequest: MyRequest, ack: Acknowledgment) {
   //do Something with myRequest
    ack.acknowledge()
}
```

My `ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory` is

```
@Bean
fun myKafkaFactory(): ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, MyRequest> {
    val factory = ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, MyRequest>()
    factory.consumerFactory = DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory(configProps(), StringDeserializer(), MyRequestDeserializer())
    factory.containerProperties.ackMode = ContainerProperties.AckMode.MANUAL
    return factory
}
```

Is there a way i can create a separate consumer for each topic dynamically so that when I add one more topic to the list in `my.topics`, spring will automatically creates a separate consumer for that topic.

The problem I am facing now is, if something goes wrong with one of the messages in any of the topics, messages in other topics are also getting impacted.

On a high level, i am looking for something like this

```
@Bean
fun myKafkaFactory(): ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, MyRequest> {
    val factory = ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, MyRequest>()
    factory.consumerFactory = DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory(configProps(), StringDeserializer(), MyRequestDeserializer())
    factory.containerProperties.ackMode = ContainerProperties.AckMode.MANUAL
    factory.isOneConsumerPerTopic(true)
    return factory
}
```

so that `factory.isOneConsumerPerTopic(true)` will ensure a separate consumer is created for each topic in the Array.

I did go through [How to create separate Kafka listener for each topic dynamically in springboot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41533391/how-to-create-separate-kafka-listener-for-each-topic-dynamically-in-springboot). I am looking a bit more 'cleaner' solution. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can add a custom `PartitionAssignor` to the Kafka consumer configuration.

Set the container concurrency to (at least) the number of topics and have your assignor assign the partitions for each topic to a specific consumer(s).

```
/**
 * This interface is used to define custom partition assignment for use in
 * {@link org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer}. Members of the consumer group subscribe
 * to the topics they are interested in and forward their subscriptions to a Kafka broker serving
 * as the group coordinator. The coordinator selects one member to perform the group assignment and
 * propagates the subscriptions of all members to it. Then {@link #assign(Cluster, Map)} is called
 * to perform the assignment and the results are forwarded back to each respective members
 *
 * In some cases, it is useful to forward additional metadata to the assignor in order to make
 * assignment decisions. For this, you can override {@link #subscription(Set)} and provide custom
 * userData in the returned Subscription. For example, to have a rack-aware assignor, an implementation
 * can use this user data to forward the rackId belonging to each member.
 */
public interface PartitionAssignor {
```

You could start with the `AbstractPartitionAssignor`.

See the [spring-kafka documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.3.3.RELEASE/reference/html/#using-ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer).

> When listening to multiple topics, the default partition distribution may not be what you expect. For example, ...